# how can I create this layout in android like any.do Cal application

Tags: android, layout, view, calendar, shapes

I want to create a layout for start and end date like the one in any.do calendar application.
I have two problems 
First: how can build these two arrow shapes ?
(I wanna be able to change their colors when clicked)
Should I work with android xml shapes ?

Second: These 2 views collide with each other, how is that possible?
 As far as I know we work rectangles in xml. How can I arrange the views to intersect each other ?
Any code sample will be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Try to make android 9 patch. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html